# How to configure a Hyper-V server with VMs, PMs and a wifi hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, dhcp, hyper-v, static-ip

I have to, for the next month, run my home network off a wifi hotspot provided by my phone. I've moved house and previously this was working successfully via my router. I've had it setup using static IP addressing.

I have a number of physical machines that are plugged into a switch using ethernet (work-station, VM server, file server, laptop). The VM server has a number of VMs: SQL servers, domain controller (also DNS server). I'm using static IP addressing within my local network, but have allowed DHCP for the WIFI conenctions. My subnet mask is 255.255.0.0, as the wifi hotspot host addressing differs in the last two sets of digits.

On the VM server I've created two switches:

- WIFI Virtual External
- RJ45 Virtual External

I've shared these into the VMs within the server. They can see each other and connect to the internet, including the DC.

How do I get the other physical machines (which don't have a WIFI connection) to connect to the internet via: domain controller -> VM sevrer -> WIFI Virtual External -> hot spot

Comment: You could share your PC internet connection via Ethernet with the physical computers. See [example link](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/share-internet-connection-windows-ethernet-wi-fi).

Comment: @harrymc - after having managed to lose the ability to remove into my VM server (and having to faff around finding old monitor and keyboard etc, I have now done this. Works a treat. Your pointer much appreciated. If you'd like to paste this in as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it so.

Comment: Answer is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical computers that can only connect via Ethernet, can share your PC
internet connection, in effect transforming it into an Ethernet hotspot.

- Run *Start > Network and Sharing Centre*
- Click your internet connection
- In the dialog, click Properties
- In the new dialog, click the Sharing tab
- Toggle "Allow other network users to connect" to On
- Select the relevant Ethernet port from the pulldown menu
- Click OK.

For more details see the article
[How to Share Your Internet Connection in Windows Using Ethernet or Wi-Fi](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/share-internet-connection-windows-ethernet-wi-fi).